Gatling, ignore in report all time out failures
How to ignore in report all time out fails.
If for 30 seconds ws did not find the suitable message forever loop must start new iteration, and doesn`t mark the request as failed on timeout, it must just ignore it.
I added optional function but it did not help, silent is not suitable for me, i need to see the count of  "[WS] wait message" in the report, in general my task is to count the number of messages that ws received for 30 seconds
`.exec(forever().on(ws("Send message", "some_ws_name")
          .sendText(session -> "2")
          .await(30)
          .on(ws.checkTextMessage("[WS] wait the 1 message")
                  .check(regex("42\\[\"message.+").optional()))
 ));`

